# Linking Header Files

Tags: c, pointers, header-files, compiler-warnings

I built a stack data structure, which has a `peek` method. The compiler is giving me a `warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast` warning when calling `peek` in main. Here is what I have:

`stack.h`:

```
struct stack_elem {
    struct stack_elem *next;
};

struct stack {
    struct stack_elem *top;
};

void stack_init(struct stack *stack);
int isEmpty(struct stack *);
struct stack_elem * peak(struct stack *);
```

And its implementation:

```
void stack_init(struct stack *stack) {
    stack->top = NULL;
}

int isEmpty(struct stack *stack) {  
    if (stack->top == NULL) 
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

struct stack_elem * peek(struct stack *stack) { 
    if (isEmpty(stack) == 1)  
        return NULL;
    else
        return stack->top;
}
```

In my `main.c`, I define stack as follows:

```
struct stack stack;
stack_init(&stack);
```

and call peek:

```
struct stack_elem * elem = peek(&stack);
```

This line throws the warning. The weird thing here is that I used to import `stack.c` into `main.c` and just compile with `$ gcc main.c`. This had absolutely no errors. Now I changed the import to `stack.h`, and I am compiling with `$ gcc main.c stack.c` which throws the warnings. Running it also segfaults (which it didn't beforehand).

Comment: can you give all source code ?

Comment: why your declaration contains a statement : `node->value.character = *p; `?

Comment: @Aftnix sorry I fixed it. I copied it from an emacs split screen and it copied by mistake.

Comment: @laifjei the source code is very long. Would you rather a github link or 3 pastebin links with the code?

Comment: You need to be compiling with more warnings enabled.  Your compiler should tell you about undeclared functions — or implicitly declared functions.  With `gcc`, I use `gcc -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes` at minimum (usually `-Wextra` too, and some other rather specific flags to deal with the eccentricities of the old code that I have to work with).  This would have told you that `peek()` was not declared (so it was assumed to be a function returning an `int`).

Comment: When is your stack going to be able to store values?  So far, your questions have all been about stacks that can only store pointers to other parts of the stack, and not any values.  You also seem to be deleting questions...that's not very nice.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Don't worry about my stack. It works fine now. I created a stack that does not require dynamic memory allocation. PRetty much a C++ stack template, in C. All those errors were because of my peek mistake. I will include your gcc flags into my makefile. Thanks!

Comment: I actually suggested an edit to your post by changing `peak` to `peek`. Hah !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
struct stack_elem * peak(struct stack *);
```

To:

```
struct stack_elem * peek(struct stack *);
```

: )

Comment: Damn it - mistakes like these make me want to bang my head to the wall 10 times. It was working all long when it shouldn't have. Thanks a lot! I guess it needed a fresh pair of eyes.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like peek()  isn't declared in the .h, so the compiler is assuming it's an int.  main() is calling it an assuming it's a pointer return type.

The warning is 100% correct!

Answer (score 3):

Seems to me there is a typo in your header file?

```
struct stack_elem * peak(struct stack *);
```

"peak", your implementation reads "peek". Don't know if that may cause such a warning, though.

Comment: It will cause the warning; `peek()` is implicitly declared to be a function returning an `int`, and hence the conversion being warned about occurs.